# Two Servo motors don't work as required (Arduino Mega 2560)

Tags: servo

Can anyone help me with the following codes? I have attached sensors to detect either plastic or metal materials. If the sensor detected a metal, the first servo will rotate at least 90 degrees. If not, it will not rotate. If its a plastic material, the other servo will do the same. Kindly consider the following codes.

```
// Include Libraries
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Button.h"
// Pin Definitions
#define REFLECTIVEIR_PIN_COLL  A1
#define REFLECTIVEIR_PIN_COLL_M  A3
// object initialization
Button ReflectiveIR(REFLECTIVEIR_PIN_COLL);
Button ReflectiveIR_M(REFLECTIVEIR_PIN_COLL_M);
// define vars for testing menu
const int timeout = 10000;       //define timeout of 10 sec
char menuOption = 0;
long time0;

#include <Servo.h>
#define redpin 2
#define bluepin 3
#define greenpin 4
#define redpin_M 5
#define bluepin_M 6
#define greenpin_M 7
int metalsensor = A0;
int metalsensor_M = A2;
int plasticsensor = A4;
//int anothersensor = A2;

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
Servo myservo_M;  // create servo object to control a servo
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 165;    // variable to store the servo position
int pos_M = 158;    // variable to store the servo position

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  myservo_M.attach(10);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  pinMode(redpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluepin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenpin, OUTPUT);
  //metal sensor
  pinMode(redpin_M, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluepin_M, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenpin_M, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(metalsensor, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(metalsensor_M, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(plasticsensor, INPUT_PULLUP);
  //  pinMode(anothersensor, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  analogWrite(redpin, 255);
  analogWrite(bluepin, 255);
  analogWrite(greenpin, 255);
  analogWrite(redpin_M, 255);
  analogWrite(bluepin_M, 255);
  analogWrite(greenpin_M, 255);
  //ReflectiveIR.init();
  //ReflectiveIR_M.init();
}

void loop() {

  int sensor_read_m = digitalRead(metalsensor);
  int sensor_read_mm = digitalRead(metalsensor_M);
  int sensor_read = digitalRead(plasticsensor);
  Serial.println("metal sensor");
  Serial.println(sensor_read_m);
  Serial.println(sensor_read_mm);
  Serial.println("plastic sensor");
  Serial.println(sensor_read);

  bool ReflectiveIR_Val = ReflectiveIR.read();
  bool ReflectiveIR_Val_M = ReflectiveIR_M.read();
  //Plastic bin
  if ((sensor_read == 0) && (sensor_read_m != 1)) {
    for (pos = 160; pos >= 90; pos -= 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
      // in steps of 1 degree
      myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(1);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
    }
    analogWrite(redpin, 255);
    analogWrite(bluepin, 0);
    analogWrite(greenpin, 255);
    delay(2500);
    for (pos = 90; pos <= 160; pos += 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
      myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(1);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position

    }
    analogWrite(redpin, 0);
    analogWrite(bluepin, 0);
    analogWrite(greenpin, 0);

  }

  else if (ReflectiveIR_Val == 1) { //checking the volume of the trash
    analogWrite(redpin, 0);
    analogWrite(bluepin, 255);
    analogWrite(greenpin, 255);

  }

  else {
    // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position


    analogWrite(redpin, 255);
    analogWrite(bluepin, 255);
    analogWrite(greenpin, 255);

  }

  //metal sensor

  if (sensor_read_mm == 1) {
    for (pos_M = 160; pos_M >= 90; pos_M -= 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
      // in steps of 1 degree
      myservo_M.write(pos_M);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(1);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
    }
    analogWrite(redpin_M, 255);
    analogWrite(bluepin_M, 0);
    analogWrite(greenpin_M, 255);
    delay(2500);
    for (pos_M = 90; pos_M <= 160; pos_M += 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
      myservo_M.write(pos_M);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(1);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position

    }
    analogWrite(redpin_M, 0);
    analogWrite(bluepin_M, 0);
    analogWrite(greenpin_M, 0);

  }

  else if (ReflectiveIR_Val_M == 1) {
    analogWrite(redpin_M, 0);
    analogWrite(bluepin_M, 255);
    analogWrite(greenpin_M, 255);

  }

  else {
    // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo_M.write(pos_M);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position


    analogWrite(redpin_M, 255);
    analogWrite(bluepin_M, 255);
    analogWrite(greenpin_M, 255);

  }

}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The servo don't respond to any type of material (plastic or metal). Can you help me solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I can't figure out how it would work using the sensors that will make the servo response. Can you help me find the correct codes to make it work? Thank you.

Comment: your code right now is `read sensor ... if metal then flash LEDs and move servo`   .... do instead at beginning of loop() `read sensor ... if metal then set flag  (metal=true)` .... further down in loop() `if metal then move servo` .... `if metal then flash leds`   ..... that way everything is separated and you can easily print debugging info about the state of flags

Comment: Thanks. I would try to change the codes according to what you suggest. I'll get back later for updates.

Comment: start with the detect code .... forget about servos and leds .... well maybe use the led to indicate detection of material and another led to indicate type of material

Comment: I really can't figure out which of the codes I will change or modify. It would be greatly appreciated If you don't mind changing it for me. I am new to this. Some codes were taken from online sources. I understand what you mean but I find it hard for me to figure out which specifically I will change. Thanks for the help.

Comment: start by commenting out all code in loop() except the first 8 lines .... see what values get printed for each of the materials that you want to detect .... slow down the loop() by including `delay 200;` before end of loop()

Comment: The detection creates loops continuously even nothing is detected. The servo for metal sensor rotates back and forth. I really don't know how to change the codes to make it right. Could you please fix it for me? I am new to Arduino coding.

Comment: you are the only one who can figure out if the sensors are working and what data values the sensors produce ... it is not possible to write the code to do something without knowing what the inputs are

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it. But, anyway, I will try to find it out how to make it work the way it is suppose to.

Comment: like i said before, get the detection code working first ..... if you cannot differentiate between metal and plastic, then it is pointless to write code for the servos .... good luck with your project